# How can I display Array items in a TextView by clicking button

Tags: java, android, for-loop, button, switch-statement

I'm developing an Android app and I'm trying to display all the months of the year in a TextView. I need to show every month one per one by button click.

This is the way I was thinking it could work.

```
    package com.flixarts.ar.englishnow;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import org.w3c.dom.Text;

    public class saludos extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView espacioFrases;
    private Button next;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_saludos);
            monthsDisplay =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.espacioFrases);
            next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //formularFrases();


        }
    });

}

String [] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September","October", "November", "December"};
String monthToDisplay = "";

public void showMonths(){

    for (int i=0 ; i<frases.length; i = i+1) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0 :
                monthToDisplay = months[i];
                monthDisplay.setText(monthToDisplay);
            case 1 :
                fraseamostrar = months[i];
                monthDisplay.setText(monthToDisplay);
            case 2 :
                fraseamostrar = months[i];
                monthDisplay.setText(monthToDisplay);
            case 3 :
                fraseamostrar = months[i];
                monthDisplay.setText(monthToDisplay);
            case 4 :
                fraseamostrar = months[i];
                monthDisplay.setText(monthToDisplay);
            case 5 :
                fraseamostrar = months[i];
                monthDisplay.setText(monthToDisplay);
            case 6 :
                fraseamostrar = months[i];
                monthDisplay.setText(monthToDisplay);

        }


    }




}
```

The problem here is that only displays me the first month, January, because everytime I call the showMonths() method, the variable "i" is inicialized in 0, so always will show me the first month.
I want to save the value of a variable i and increment by one (i++) so I can display all the months, but everytime I call the function i is inicialized to 0.

Comment: When you click on the button, do you want to show Jan to Dec?

Comment: please add break; statements after every case statement ends

Answer (score 0):

Save current index

```
String [] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September","October", "November", "December"};
int currentMonthIdx = 0;
```

After that you'll be able to call this function on every button click:

```
public void onButtonClick() {
    currentMonthIdx = (currentMonthIdx + 1) % months.length;
    monthsDisplay.setText(months[currentMonthIdx]);
}
```

Do not forget to display first month at startup:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saludos);
        monthsDisplay =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.espacioFrases);
        monthsDisplay.setText(months[0]);
}
```

Comment: Ivan now I can see all the months January, February, March... December on button click. But it goes again to January after December, do you know how can I stop it after december?

Comment: Just replace "currentMonthIdx = (currentMonthIdx + 1) % months.length" with "currentMonthIdx++;". Also you need to check the bounds otherwise you will catch OutOfBoundsException...

Comment: if (currentMonthIdx < months.length) {
    monthsDisplay.setText(months[currentMonthIdx]);
}

Answer (score 0):

```
public void showMonths(){

    for (int i=0 ; i<frases.length; i = i+1) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0 :
                monthToDisplay = months[i];
                monthDisplay.setText(monthToDisplay);
        break;
            case 1 :
                fraseamostrar = months[i];
                monthDisplay.setText(monthToDisplay);
        break;
            case 2 :
                fraseamostrar = months[i];
                monthDisplay.setText(monthToDisplay);
        break;
            case 3 :
                fraseamostrar = months[i];
                monthDisplay.setText(monthToDisplay);
        break;
            case 4 :
                fraseamostrar = months[i];
                monthDisplay.setText(monthToDisplay);
        break;
            case 5 :
                fraseamostrar = months[i];
                monthDisplay.setText(monthToDisplay);
        break;
            case 6 :
                fraseamostrar = months[i];
                monthDisplay.setText(monthToDisplay);
        break;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show next month for every click try below code.

```
package onsource.com.onsourceinspector.data.api;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView; 

public class saludos extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView monthsDisplay;
int i = 0;
private Button next;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saludos);
    monthsDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.espacioFrases);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showMonths();
        }
    });
}

String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
String monthToDisplay = "";

public void showMonths() {
    if (i > 11)
        i = 0;      
    monthsDisplay.setText(months[i++]);
 }    
}
```